# How to give pop-up alert box for duplication validation in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Table: **dept**  Field: **dept_code** in mysql table by php form. I need the duplication validation. Using the code `ALTER TABLE tableName ADD CONSTRAINT tb_UQ UNIQUE (area_code)` it works well by database. But I need a pop-up alert box in the php form when click submit button.

Comment: You should manually check the existence in the database with the help of AJAX and show the pop-up with message. MySQL constraint will throw the exception and for that you need to use exception handling.

Comment: @SSNath Unique constraint is not defined on field `dept_code`?